# How to reverse iterate a nested for loop in python?

Tags: python, string, substring, reverse, palindrome

There exists a string s = "abcd"

How do I iterate through the string such that it produces the following output for its index:

```
3
32
321
3210
```

I have written the following code:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(s))):
    for j in range(i, -1, -1):
        print(j, end='')
    print()
```

It gives me the output:

```
3210
210
10
0
```

How do I achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Think about solving the inverse problem:

```
0
01
012
0123
```

That solution seems pretty easy, and the only change to produce your result is subtracting from `len(s)-1`.

```
s = "abcd"
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(len(s)-j-1, end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.